# Regex for Alphanumeric Values and not two consecutive underscores underscore

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, lwc

I have a requirement in javascript to write a regex for the following condition

**The Custom Metadata Record MasterLabel field can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must be unique, begin with a letter, not include spaces, not end with an underscore, and not contain two consecutive underscores.**

If we leave out the unique part since we have to check it with the system records i need a regex for testing the other conditions mentioned above.

Here is an expression ive built so far but it doesnt seem to work. I am new to the regular expressions so any help would be appreciated.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9][^ ][^__])[^_]*$/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
^(?!_|\d)(?!.*__)(?!.*_$)\w+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0hUsae/1).

---

In `JavaScript`:

```js
const regex = /^(?!_)(?!.*__)(?!.*_$)\w+$/gm;
const str = `_
A
abcd
_
123
some_spaces 
not_any_spaces__
1test34
correct_thing`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The string has all the required properties if and only if it matches the following regular expression:

```
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*(?:_[a-z\d]+)*$/i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/42YbOK/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
/
^           # match beginning of string
[a-z]       # match a letter
[a-z\d]*    # match one or more alphanumeric characters
(?:         # begin non-capture group
   _        # match an underscore
  [a-z\d]+  # match one or more alphanumeric characters
)*          # end non-capture group and execute it zero or more times
$           # match end of string
/i          # specify matches of letters to be case-indifferent
```

Notice that the way I prevent the presence of two underscores in a row has the fortuitous side-effect of ensuring that the last character in the string is not an underscore (a freebie!).

Comment: I always love it when RegEx solutions are broken down in such a detail!

Comment: There  is nothing wrong in `(?:_[a-z\d]+)*`. Both patterns inside the group are obligatory, they do not match the same strings, so there is no backtracking problems with this. This will match "big" strings just fine.

Comment: I think this solution is easier to read than the solution of Jan